# Service does not work well with *ngIf in Angular2

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, angular-meteor, angular2-meteor

**EDIT: Hmm, I should be more clear. This is an angular2-meteor project. Because meteor is reactive, so maybe has other ways. But @lodewijk-bogaards is an good solution for pure Angular2 project.**

I am using Angular 2 (TypeScript).

I try to use `ChatService` service to pass value "12345" from `App` to `ChatDetailsComponent`.

If the boolean `showChatDetails` is true, it will show "12345" the first time I click the Show button, which works well.

The problem is, if the boolean `showChatDetails` is false, it will show "12345" after the second time I click the Show button. I don't know why it works the second time I click it, which should be first time too.

(Please don't switch to [hidden], because I need *ngIf here.)

// app.ts

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ChatService} from './chat.service';
import {ChatDetailsComponent} from './chat-details.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app'
})
@View({
    directives: [ChatDetailsComponent],
    template: `
        <button (click)="showButton()">Show</button>
        <chat-details-component *ngIf="showChatDetails"></chat-details-component>
    `
})
class App {
    // Here if it is true, it works well. If it is false, the problem comes.
    showChatDetails:boolean = false;  

    constructor(private _chatService: ChatService) {}

    showButton() {
        this._chatService.setChatId("12345");
        this.showChatDetails = true;
    }
}

bootstrap(App, [ChatService]);
```

// chat-details.component.ts

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {ChatService} from './chat.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'chat-details-component'
})
@View({
    template: `
        <div>ID: {{chatId}}</div>
    `
})
export class ChatDetailsComponent {
    chatId:string;

    constructor(private _chatService: ChatService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._chatService.getChatId().subscribe(id => this.chatId = id);
    }
}
```

// chat.service.ts

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

export class ChatService {
    chatId: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

    setChatId(id) {
        this.chatId.emit(id);
    }

    getChatId() {
        return this.chatId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a race condition to me. If the `ChatDetailsComponent` subscribes to the `ChatService` *after* the `chatId` has been emitted it will not receive it. This is very easily possible, since Angular will schedule the creation of the component at the same time as Rx schedules the emit of the event.

I can come up with multiple solutions, but I would suggest that you look into using a [ReplaySubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md) instead of an EventEmitter.

Comment: Thanks, Lodewijk! Actually it is an angular2-meteor project. Since meteor is reactive, and I haven't seen any meteor with RxJS project yet. So I will wait a little bit time for other answers.

Comment: Just tried with ReplaySubject, worked like a charm!. This is the correct answer and the explanation is correct as well.

Comment: Actually `EventEmitter` *is* simply a RxJs `Subject` and Angular 2 requires RxJs, so I can't imagine it not being present in angular2-meteor.

Comment: @LodewijkBogaards yeah, you are right, I just realize the relationship between EventEmitter and Rx. However, I only find EventEmitter in `angular2/core.d.ts`, but no Rx. So I cannot use Rx.abc directly. It probably gonna take me some time to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your aim is to accomplish the task the very way you stated or if you're flexible in how it's done.

I think it's much less error prone to make chatId an `@Input()` of `ChatDetailsComponent` and have `App` create a new instance of the component whenever `chatId` changes.

The containing component has to know when an instance of `ChatDetailsComponent` needs to be created anyway. Having it pass the needed `chatId` irhgt away seems to be a better approach to me.